# Read an XML file from a website using forms based authentication

Tags: asp.net, xml, forms-authentication

Is there a standard way to read an XML file from a website that uses forms based authentication? We want to read the file into a desktop app.

thanks - dave

Comment: Thanks all. I was 99% certain we had to duplicate the web requests. But I was hoping there was an alternative approach. Oh well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about [ASP.NET Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) this will be a two step process:

1. Send an HTTP request to the login page sending the username and password and capturing the authentication cookie  sent by the server
2. Send an HTTP request to the script returning the XML file sending the authentication cookie along with the request

Here's an example using a custom [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer Cookies { get; private set; }
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
    {
        Cookies = new CookieContainer();
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.CookieContainer = Cookies;
        return request;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
        {
            client.UploadValues("http://www.foo.com/login.aspx", new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "username", "foo" },
                { "password", "secret" },
            });
            client.DownloadFile("http://www.foo.com/foo.xml", "foo.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course in the real life things might be more complex because depending on the site you might need to send along ViewState and other ASP.NET specific crap along with the request.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. That means we have to track the login page and the editboxes to populate. Uck.

Answer (score 1):

post the credentials in an http request, on the response there will be an authentication cookie that you have to reuse for your next requests

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use HTTPWebRequest/HTTPWebResponse in roughly the following steps:

1: Use a request to submit the username and password to the website
2: Save the Cookies (I assume the cookies will contain the ok that the login worked)
3: Use another request, including these cookies, to get the XML.

To find the code that for the initial request you will need to look at the source code of the login page to see the submission action, and then reproduce this through your request. You may be able to use fiddler or firebug etc to help working this out.